# How to use different environments with `.env` files in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, dotenv

I am currently building a backend in nodejs. I am thinking about how to add an environment configuration to the project. My idea is that I have a `/config` folder in which I have my `envparser.ts` (have to think about a better name for this ^^) which interprets my `.env` files to use them as regular javascript const. By using scripts in my `package.json` I would like to have the ability to switch the envs. But I don´t know how to switch between multiple `.env` files using dotenv.

**File structure:**

```
config/
   .env.development
   .env.production
   envparser.ts
```

**Scripts:**

> ```
> yarn start
> yarn start -p/-production //Or a different Syntax to change envs
> ```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `dotenv` package for accessing ur `.env.*` files.

---

You can switch between different environments by changing the `NODE_ENV` variable using the different started commands in `package.json`

For eg:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon index.js",
    "deploy": "NODE_ENV=production node index.js"
}
```

And then, u can access them in your index.js file as :

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}` })
```

Answer (score 8):

You can have something like this in your scripts section in `package.json`

```
"start:dev": "node -r dotenv/config your_script.js dotenv_config_path=/custom/path/to/.env.development", 
"start:prod": "node -r dotenv/config your_script.js dotenv_config_path=/custom/path/to/.env.production"
```

start server in `DEV` mode by running `npm run start:dev`

start server in `PROD` mode by running `npm run start:prod`

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like this in your scripts section in `package.json`:

```
"dev": "nodemon -r dotenv/config index.js"
```

[image]